# Searching command history in any interpreter

Tags: terminal, readline

By running an interpreter trough `rlwrap` I have access to the command history by pressing the up and down arrow keys. However, I would like to be able to search the command history like I do in Bash (with Ctrl-r). Is there an alternative to `rlwrap` which has this feature? By the way I use `rlwrap` version 0.43.

Edit: This problem seems to be related to GNU APL. For other command line interpreters the Ctrl-r command works as expected.

Comment: No, the problem is not APL-related at all: it happens for all interpreters that do their own line editing (like erlang, Node.js, and many more) The solution is to use an extra `-a` option with `rlwrap` (see my answer below)

Comment: @HansLub I see, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `rlwrap` manpage:

```
-a, --always-readline [password_prompt]
          Always  remain in "readline mode", regardless of command's
          terminal settings.  Use this option if you want to use 
          rlwrap with commands that already do some line editing.
```

If your interpreter (or any command you want to `rlwrap`) already has a command history mechanism it is clearly one of those commands.

The way to use `rlwrap` in such a case is (using the GNU APL interpreter `apl` as an example):

```
$ rlwrap --always-readline apl
```

Be aware, however, that this will override any existing (and, for `apl`, apparently, [very APL-specific](https://www.gnu.org/software/apl/apl.html#Section-3_002e10) history and completion mechanism). How to avoid this (spoiler: you can't!) is actually one of the [most often asked FAQs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210931/can-rlwrap-use-a-wrapped-commands-own-tab-completion) about `rlwrap`

If you omit the `--always-readline` then `rlwrap` will remain "transparent", i.e. it will just hand down all your keypresses to the rlwrapped command, and do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me out of the box on Debian with <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd>:

```
$ rlwrap --version
rlwrap 0.42
$ rlwrap cat > /dev/null 
foo
bar
(reverse-i-search)`f': foo
```

`/etc/inputrc` and `~/.inputrc` apply to Readline even with `rlwrap`, so they might affect what bindings are available. (But then you did imply it works in Bash, so it's probably not about `inputrc`.)

Comment: Your example works for me too. The interpreter I'm having problem with, however, is GNU APL. I find this strange since, as far as I understand, rlwrap should intercept all keystrokes.